# Linking libwebsockets library

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I have searched alot but didn't find anything reasonable to me. I want to link https://libwebsockets.org to a C program. I have tried using builds available here https://ci.appveyor.com/project/lws-team/libwebsockets but those were giving errors when i used websocket server code available here https://gist.github.com/martinsik/3216369
I got these errors when i used build with webserver code

[image: Errors when i used the websocket server code]

Build Log
[image: Build log]

I want to know how to build this library myself and i tried notes available here https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-master/html/md_READMEs_README_8build.html but it was too complicated for me to understand. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you switch into `Build log` tab and read detailed compiler error output from there. It seems like library API of websokets you are using is newer then used in example code, so you need to make changes in your code or find newer example somewhere in github.

Comment: @VictorGubin i have added the build log output

Comment: Goto menu bar and choose  `Build->Rebuild`. 2. Have you added websockets incude and library directories to the [compiler and linker search patch](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/).

Comment: One of those questions with images and links...

Comment: @VictorGubin Yeah i have added include and and library directories to the search path but still same errors